# Laravel built in auth with user image

Tags: php, laravel-5.3

I'm using Laravel built in auth system that can be found easily with running `php artisan make:auth` command in a new Laravel project. While registering I would like to give the user, the ability to upload their profile picture too.

So I have added a new field called profile_picture in the registration form. How do I receive the file from backend? I have tried adding the `Request $request` argument to the create method after array $data, but it says:

> Type error: Argument 1 passed to App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController::create() must be an instance of Illuminate\Http\Request, none given, called in /home/tawsif/laravel/repto_events/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/RegistersUsers.php on line 33`

The register controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\User;
use Validator;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;


class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Register Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles the registration of new users as well as their
    | validation and creation. By default this controller uses a trait to
    | provide this functionality without requiring any additional code.
    |
    */

    use RegistersUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login / registration.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/home';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }

    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => 'required|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed',
            'profession' => 'required|min:3',
            'phone' => 'required|digits:11',
            'address' => 'required|min:5'
            // 'profile_picture' => 'required|image'
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return User
     */
    protected function create(Request $request, array $data )
    {

         $user = User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
            'phone' => $data['phone'],
            'ssc_year' => $data['ssc'],
            'hsc_year' => $data['hsc'],
            'profession' => $data['profession'],
            'address' => $data['address'],
        ]);

      $file = $request->file('profile_picture');
      $thumbnail_path = public_path('uploads/propic/thumbnail/');
      $original_path = public_path('uploads/propic/original/');
      $file_name = 'user_'. $user->id .'_'. str_rand(32) . '.' . $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
        Image::make($file)
              ->resize(261,null,function ($constraint) {
                $constraint->aspectRatio();
                 })
              ->save($original_path . $file_name)
              ->resize(90, 90)
              ->save($thumbnail_path . $file_name);

      $user->update(['profile_picture' => $file_name]);
      return $user;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you change the form in the view to multipart?

Comment: No need to add `Request $request`. The `'profile_picture'` should come with `$data` container. Use `dd($data)` and see the value of `profile_picture`

Comment: This comment may not solve your problem but there is a issue with `$user->id`. In the create method you do not have any `$user->id`. The `$user` variable inside `create()` method is to create a new row, it didn't fetch any row. So, the `$user` has no any `id`. If you want to get upcoming user id you can use this: 
`$query = DB::select(DB::Raw("SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'users'"));`
`$id = $query[0]->Auto_increment;`

Answer (score 0):

Try moving $request to first position:

```
protected function create(Request $request, array $data)
    {
    .....
```

PS: don't work if return the user created... or is only test?, xD

Answer (score 0):

Add a new `__contruct` method as follows:

```
protected $request;

public function __contruct(Request $request)
{
    $this->request = $request;
}
```

And in your create method:

```
protected function create(Request $request, array $data )
    {

         $user = User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
            'phone' => $data['phone'],
            'ssc_year' => $data['ssc'],
            'hsc_year' => $data['hsc'],
            'profession' => $data['profession'],
            'address' => $data['address'],
        ]);

      $file = $this->request->file('profile_picture');
      $thumbnail_path = public_path('uploads/propic/thumbnail/');
      $original_path = public_path('uploads/propic/original/');
      $file_name = 'user_'. $user->id .'_'. str_rand(32) . '.' . $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
        Image::make($file)
              ->resize(261,null,function ($constraint) {
                $constraint->aspectRatio();
                 })
              ->save($original_path . $file_name)
              ->resize(90, 90)
              ->save($thumbnail_path . $file_name);

      $user->update(['profile_picture' => $file_name]);
      return $user;
    }
```